# JSON coming back with syntax error? (IMGUR API)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp, imgur

**ETA: Here's the JSFiddle, check your console: http://jsfiddle.net/GZNwK/1/**

So I'm just trying to load a subreddit from the IMGUR API:

```
$.getJSON('http://imgur.com/r/cats.json?callback=?',function(data){
    console.log(data)
})
```

But I end up with this error:

[image]

Not exactly sure why this is. I can load the Flickr API and the Instagram API in .jsom format, the syntax *appears* to be exactly the same. Why is the IMGUR API giving me an error? Also, if I remove ?callback=? then it it doesn't use JSONP and the cross-domain request fails.

Comment: You simply linked us jsfiddle.net. You have to save your fiddle before you can copy and paste the link. I do that mistake a lot, too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this is not a resource that supports JSONP requests. I don't know a whole lot about IMGUR, but it looks like they do have an API you can use: http://api.imgur.com/

Another solution would be to use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
    data: {
        q: 'select * from json where url="http://imgur.com/r/cats.json"',
        format: 'json'
    },
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
}).success(function (data) {
    /* results are in data.query.results.json.gallery */
    alert(data.query.results.json.gallery[0].title);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/sNSEA/

Although I would strongly recommend doing this the "right" way through the API if possible (a quick glance didn't yield anything).

Comment: @JacksonGariety, You will have to proxy it over from your server.  Since JSONP isn't available, there is no way to bypass the restrictions and get it client-side.

Comment: @JacksonGariety: You can also use YQL. One second and I'll get an example working

Comment: I thought I was using their API. Their docs dont say anything about grabbign subreddits. How could I use their API to grab imgur.com/r/cats page?

Comment: I don't think you're using their API. I think that's just a resource on their site that happens to serve up JSON.

Comment: Oh, thanks. But your YQL thing worked! Unfortunately, for some reason, all the "source" items are null! Any idea why the source values are lost.

Comment: If you navigate to the JSON resource in your browser you'll notice that there are many null values for the `source` property... YQL isn't changing them to null.